# FilePicker / FileStack Error: The specified policy does not allow the call remove

Tags: amazon-s3, filepicker.io, filepicker

I am using Filepicker.io now called FileStack and I am trying to delete a file through the API and am getting this error:

This action has been secured by the developer of this website. Error: The specified policy does not allow the call remove

Has anyone seen this before? I am sending files through FilePicker to Amazon S3 so my questions are:

1. How can I resolve this?
2. Is this an issue on Amazon S3 side or FilePicker side?

Answer (score 2):

This is filepicker API error message and it indicate that owner of the file 
( filepicker app owner ) is using security mode.

If security is enabled all actions required `policy` and `signature` appended.

If you are app owner you can generate proper `policy` and `signature` base on your filepicker app secret key.

See more: https://www.filestack.com/docs/security/

https://www.filestack.com/docs/file-ingestion/javascript-api/remove